# Entity Framework initialization is SLOW -- what can I do to bootstrap it faster?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.3

My EF 4.3.1 model has 200-odd tables.  Initial startup is horrible, several minutes.  A DotTrace-captured profile implies some terrible algorithm/scalability choices deep in the framework, as evidenced by the millions of calls to a number of methods down there and the 36 million IEnumerable.Contains() calls.  Here is a snippet, this is all triggered by the first query done on the database (future queries don't do this and are fine).

[image]

What can I do to my model to make this less painful?  Can I precompile this somehow?  Better, can the EF team please address these issues or open source the framework so I can?  Or at least fix the spelling of `Warapper`? :)

EDIT: One specific EF call that triggers this is basically `var db = new MyDbContext(); db.Personnel.Where(a => a.Login == login).SingleOrDefault();`.  Also an EF Migrations Seed() AddOrUpdate generates effectively the same stack.  The fuller stack trace, which may give a little more context, is here: [Fuller Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH9v8.png)

EDIT: Some relevant links:

- MSDN: [Performance Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (thanks to @AakashM)
- MSDN: [EF Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx)
- SO: [Entity Framework 4.1 for large number of tables (715)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185918/entity-framework-4-1-for-large-number-of-tables-715)

EDIT2: Now that they just [open sourced](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) the code, it appears that this line:

```
//Filter the 1:1 foreign key associations to the ones relating the sets used in these cell wrappers.
oneToOneForeignKeyAssociationsForThisWrapper =
    oneToOneForeignKeyAssociationsForThisWrapper.Where(
        it => (it.AssociationEndMembers.All(endMember => entityTypes.Contains(endMember.GetEntityType()))));
```

is the one that needs some work.  It's using an O(n^2) algorithm when it probably doesn't have to, but I haven't looked closely yet.

EDIT3: Happily, it looks like work in EF6 is fixing this code: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/396130

Comment: Can you `porovide` the c# example code that created this trace?

Comment: @Erik Philips: Sure (edited question) but it's trivial.

Comment: First port of call should be [Performance Considerations (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you havne't been there already - check the version number btw

Comment: @AakashM: Thanks.  I looked, good read.  At least they KNOW it's slow.  ;)

Comment: In this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18807355/325727 I've had a similar problem where UnityIoC was causing millions of framework calls as seen in DotNetTrace. Unfortunately this was never solved, and we ended up dropping Unity as a result.

Answer (score 23):

In pre EF6 view generation is known to be slow for bigger models. For now the solution is to use pregenerated views. This way you generate views at design time and are avoiding this work at runtime. To do that download EF power tools and select "Optimize Entity Data Model". It will add a C# file to your project that contains views. The down side is that you will need to do it each time your model changes. Note: to generate views with the tool it will take about the same amount of time it takes to generate views at runtime (so sometimes you need to be patient). Here is a post about EF Power Tools that might be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx

**Edit**

Recently I created a different solution that is much more convenient to use (note it only works on EF6) - http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/12/14/using-pre-generated-views-without-having-to-pre-generate-views-ef6/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that and try to post results here. Do you think there are software improvements that can be made in future versions to speed this process up, or is there simply too much to compute, and it's as optimized as it'll get (implying I have to chop things up or out)?

Comment: We are looking at possible ways to make it better.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Best of luck... happy to lend support if possible.

Comment: No, thanks a ton for the advice.  Very happy to see you guys trawling SO.

Comment: ... at the moment I'm at a fail for using the EF Power Tools Beta 2, getting "Sequence contains no elements".

Comment: That's too bad. Do you have more details on this (stack trace would be helpful) or a repro.

Comment: Is there some way to extract a stack trace?  There's nothing in the Debug window or the popup, just that message.  I posted to a thread of reports on this: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/view/Discussions#4307

Comment: @ Scott Stafford :I have the same error:"Sequence contains no elements",did you find where the problem is?

Comment: Link to EF Power Tools is broken

Answer (score 12):

Here is another way to do it. It requires a bit manual work but can actually be more suited to your scenario where you would like to use MsBuild. Instead of creating views with Power Tools (I am sorry to hear that they did not work for you) you can create them manually - here are the steps:

- First you need to get artifacts for your context. You need all - csdl, ssdl and msl files. You can use EdmxWriter to get these. Note that EdmxWriter returns an edmx file that combines all three files so you need to split them. Here is the code for this step (note that namespaces are specific to EF4, if you are thinking about using EF5 and .NET Framework 4.5 you will need to change them accordingly or select elements only by local name and not the fully qualified name):

```
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(new Context(), writer);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;

    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(ms);

    var ssdl = xDoc.Descendants("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl}Schema").Single();
    var csdl = xDoc.Descendants("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm}Schema").Single();
    var msl = xDoc.Descendants("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/mapping/cs}Mapping").Single();

    ssdl.Save("Context.ssdl");
    csdl.Save("Context.csdl");
    msl.Save("Context.msl");
```

- When you have artifacts you can generate views using EdmGen tool. Since here we do it manually you need to do it from the VS Command prompt. Here is the command you use to generate views:

```
EdmGen /mode:ViewGeneration /incsdl:Context.csdl  /inmsl:Context.msl /inssdl:Context.ssdl /outviews:Context.Views.cs
```

- Add the generated file to your project.

If you want to integrate view generation with your build system there is one more interesting option - using a T4 template. The template would take care of the above steps. You can find more details about this approach here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx. The only problem is that the example is not for CodeFirst approach so it needs to be changed a little bit which should not be hard.

I actually created T4 templates for Code First. You can find a link to download in my blog post: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/05/28/entity-framework-code-first-and-pre-generated-views/

The templates are now available on Visual Studio Code Gallery. Here is the link to the post with all the details: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/

Comment: Actaully now after posting this I am thinking about creating T4 templates for CodeFirst... Stay tuned.

Comment: I created view gen T4 templates for code first. The link is in my blog post: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/05/28/entity-framework-code-first-and-pre-generated-views/

Comment: Pawel's current link to C# T4 template is: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ae7730ce-ddab-470f-8456-1b313cd2c44d

Comment: Hi Pawel. What needs to be changed in this code so it can work with EF6? var ssdl = .... throws InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.

Comment: @Goran - EF5 views are not compatible with EF6 so you can't use EdmGen to generate views for EF6. If you are using CodeFirst I created EF6 specific templates to generate views - see this http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/10/17/ef6-codefirst-view-generation-t4-template-for-c-updated-for-ef6-rtm/ for more details. Alternatively, you can use EF Power Tools Beta 4 which allow creating views for CodeFirst and Edmx for EF6 - see this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/10/12/ef-power-tools-beta-4-available.aspx) post for more details.

Comment: @Pawel.Thanks for your effort in this field.EF Power doesn't support visual studio 2015 .Isn't there any other solution for saving ssdl,csdl and msl file for EF6 e.g. using System.Data.Resources.SSDLSchema_2.xsd file?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your question. xsd describes the structure of an Xml document and cannot be used to save anything. Most of the functionality of PowerTools has moved to the EF Designer that ships with VS.

Answer (score 1):

View generation is in fact quite fast in the current version of Entity Framework. (6.1) There is another, broader caching solution in preparation: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1876. You can wait for this patch to be accepted, or, if you are brave enough, you can apply it for yourself.