# DbContext VS ObjectContext

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I used to use `DbContext` for all of my DB Models, until I read [Ways to optimize Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx), after following the steps I found my self forced to switch to `ObjectContext` instead, So, There were alot of code changes to be done, but I am not sure that I doing the right thing, specially after Googling the deference I've noticed that `DbContext` is newer and better than `ObjectContext`,  and also I noticed that I lost alot of things while switching to `ObjectContext` like "Migrations" and "Find" Method and much more...

So, Is the right thing to change my code to use `ObjectContext` instead of `DbContext` to increase the speed by Pre-Generating the Views ? or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to switch to ObjectContext to get pre-generated views. I created T4 templates for generating pre-generated views for CodeFirst. Take a look here: [Entity Framework initialization is SLOW -- what can I do to bootstrap it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757019/entity-framework-initialization-is-slow-what-can-i-do-to-bootstrap-it-faster/10757821#10757821)
The T4 templates are available on Visual Studio Gallerry. Here is the [link](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/) to my blog post describing how to get and use them

Comment: Thanks alot sir, but after creating the `{Context}.Views.cs` how can i tell the DBContext to use the generated view? Thanks in advance

Comment: The name of the file tells what context should be used - if your context is called MyContext then the name of the T4 file should be MyContext.Views.cs.

Comment: Hi Pawel, thanks a lot for writing these T4 templates. I love using them. I have customized them a little and would like to use the foreign key relationship name in naming navigation properties in case of duplication. Any pointers?

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja - I am not sure what T4 templates you are talking about. The templates for view generation are just creating ESQL views for your model and mapping. They are not supposed to be customized and the model has to be correct for them to be usable. If you are talking about templates that generate code from the model/edmx file then they are built in templates that ship with VS and are also available on VS Gallery. They can be customized indeed. Unfortunately the model does not contain constraint names. However you should not get duplicate names since the names should be uniquified.

Comment: I was talking about the templates that generate code from the model. They can be added to the solution by the "Customize Reverse Engineer Templates". Indeed they are uniquified. The code that is generated isn't erroneous. It is just that the uniquification strategy also obfuscates so that one doesn't know which navigation property corresponds to which foreign key relationship. For example, I would prefer to get DebitAccounts, CreditAccounts rather than Accounts, Accounts1. For this purpose, I want to use foreign key names. I was hoping you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think there should be a way to do this but I am not really familiar with these templates so can't tell you how to achieve this from the top of my head. I think you should just ask this as a question rather than a comment - this way your question will get much more visibility and will be more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to use DbContext as it is a simplified version of the ObjectContext. If the DbContext is not suffice, the wrapped ObjectContext can be accessed from the DbContext:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
```

The "Generate Views" option is also available for Code First (DbContext) in EF Power Tools. Right-click a file derived from DbContext and select "Entity Framework" => "Generate Views". For more information see [Generating Pre-compiled Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx)

Comment: I have dbContext used in a large application and ran into one small thing where I MUST use the functionality from ObjectContext instead and ran into this post. This works well (I am hitting arbitrary SQL statements to the DB that return anonymous objects and I am trying to then serialize that return set etc.)... The SQL string I am using is definitely correct but I get another error: <myTableName> could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namaspaces are referenced correctly.. ?

Comment: Injecting [dbName].[dbo] in my SQL string fixes it - why isn't ObjectContext aware of the db name and namespacing implicitly?