# ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance causes excessive number of calls to ObjectBuilder2.PolicyList.GetNoDefault

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, service-locator, objectbuilder

In my MVC4, .NET4.5 web app using Unity IoC container, in the method IoCContainerFactory.GetControllerInstance() we use ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance to get the controller instance:

```
public class IoCControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
         System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        // snip other code
        // this is the problem line:
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```

But this has been performing too slowly. Using JetBrains DotNetTrace product I've found that ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance appears to be calling ObjectBuilder2.PolicyList.GetNoDefault more than one million times.  How can I figure out why it is making so many calls, and what can I do to fix this problem?  Attached screenshot shows the output from dotnetTrace:

[image]

And what policy is it trying to get in the method `PolicyList.GetNoDefault`?  I I knew what policy it was trying to find I could perhaps change that policy so that it does need to be checked so many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was never solved and we ended up dropping Unity in favor of LightInject, which is a significantly faster IoC implementation, as seen here:

[IoC Container Benchmark - Performance comparison](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison)

We had similar improvements when we implemented LightInject.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a remotely similar issue, but my problem resulted in a `StackOverflowException`. It was caused by a circular dependency between some of my classes.

Comment: Do I get bonus points for the genuine use of the word `StackOverflowException` on this site?