# Entity Framework Code First: pre generated views work, but startup is still slow

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, precompiled-views

I added pregenerated views to my EF project. It actually seems to be working. The `init` method gets called, the view is obviously loaded. FYI, this method is called: `DbMappingView GetView(EntitySetBase extent)`.

However, nothing changed. The startup is as slow as ever: 8 to 10 seconds. All subsequent queries are very fast.

I only have two quite small entities (20 columns together). So nothing complicated. Why is it still so slow?

Comment: I'm using EF 6.1 with the code first approach.

Comment: Code first startup is slow, some improvements to that have been made in 6.1.1 https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2258

Comment: Thanks a lot for the article. Sounds exactly like the problem I have. However I updated to EF 6.1.1 Beta 1, but the situation is still the same. Startup still takes 8 seconds:-(

Comment: Some tips here: http://romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework initialization is SLOW -- what can I do to bootstrap it faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757019/entity-framework-initialization-is-slow-what-can-i-do-to-bootstrap-it-faster)